# hi all i have a logic being implemented, my requirement is that the sum of the column should not exceed 24hrs

Tags: sql, postgresql, rdbms, azure-synapse

Ex:-Time(in minutes)

```
 12.38474
 88.47683
 8.7363
 0.19873
```

what ever the sum of the column is it should not exceed 24hrs.

Please consider the above column 'time' which has data in minutes. If the sum of all the entities is <24hrs then thats fine, however if the sum is >24hrs then the values should be capped to 24hrs example Total Time<24hrs then thats fine 
however if total time is 24.02 or 24.10 then value should be 24hrs only

could you please help in enhancing the approach

```
select round(cast(  (case when (cast(66.3763731333299 as decimal) % 1000) <> 0
                    then cast((cast((66.3763731333299 / 1000) as int) * 1000) as int) + 1000
                    else 66.3763731333299
                    end) 
                as float) / 60000, 6)
```

Please consider the above column 'time' which has data in minutes. If the sum of all the entities is <24hrs then thats fine, however if the sum is >24hrs then the values should be capped to 24hrs example Total Time<24hrs then thats fine 24.02 or 24.10 then value should be 24hrs only

Comment: Are you using Postgres or SQL Server (=Azure SQL)? Those are two very different database products

Comment: In PostgreSQL you should be able to do ˋLEAST(<your sum>, 24)ˋ.

Comment: Your code isn't processing any columns - it's using a series of constants. ???

Comment: I am using azure sql datawarehouse

Comment: For Azure: Did you try ˋto_min(scalar(<your sum>, 24)ˋ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply want `least()`?

```
select least(sum(minutes), 24 * 60)
from t;
```

Or a `case` expression:

```
select (case when sum(minutes) < 24*60 then sum(minutes else 24*60 end)
from t;
```

Comment: Ex: Sum of Time column =24.03947Hrs or 24.03 or 24.98747hrs then it should only display as 24hrs no exceeding values.
less than 24hrs is good to go however it should not exceed 24hrs

Comment: @PradyotMohanty . . . That is what this logic does.

Comment: Least is not a supported in Azure Dataware house